# foselasticabundle nested conditional search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica, foselasticabundle

here is my config

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        allstock:
            types:
                clip:
                    mappings:
                        clipInfo:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                title : { boost: 10 }
                                description : { boost: 2 }
                        filterCategories:
                            type: "nested"
                            properties:
                                tags:
                                    type: "nested"
                                    properties:
                                        tag : { boost: 5 }
                                filterCategory:
                                    type: "nested"
                                    properties:
                                        name: ~
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: Application\myBundle\Entity\Clip
                        provider: ~
                        listener: ~
                        finder: ~
```

and this is my index data

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "allstock",
        "_type": "clip",
        "_id": "11",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "clipInfo": {
            "title": "title 1",
            "description": "some desc"
          },
          "filterCategories": [
            {
              "tags": [
                {
                  "tag": "Interior"
                }
              ],
              "filterCategory": {
                "name": "Setting"
              }
            },
            {
              "tags": [
                {
                  "tag": "Sunny"
                }
              ],
              "filterCategory": {
                "name": "Season"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "allstock",
        "_type": "clip",
        "_id": "12",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "clipInfo": {
            "title": "title 2",
            "description": "desc 2"
          },
          "filterCategories": [
            {
              "tags": [
                {
                  "tag": "Sunny"
                },
                {
                  "tag": "Rainy"
                }
              ],
              "filterCategory": {
                "name": "Weather"
              }
            },
            {
              "tags": [
                {
                  "tag": "Autumn"
                },
                {
                  "tag": "Winter"
                }
              ],
              "filterCategory": {
                "name": "Season"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to build a conditional search on the `filterCategories` nested collection

```
when tag in tags  == 'sunny'
then name in filterCategory == 'Weather'
```

i.e `tag` in `tags` and `name` in `filterCategory` dependent on each other value.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Look into a `bool` query; these can be nested if necessary. Also, it is not suggested to store your mappings in your configuration file because they are easy to screw up when upgrading (e.g., forget to copy over, modify on one node, but not another, etc.).

Comment: @pickypg can you please give me some example ?

Comment: Oh... I didn't notice that _both_ subfields were also `nested`. Take a look at [a _similar_ question/answer that requires you to _unnest_ the fields and use a script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27074865/706724).