# How to access doc values of a nested array in Elasticsearch script?

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

Given the following index, how would I select  proper item in the nested array and access one of it's values? The purpose here is to use it inside the value inside a `script_score`.

```
# Create mapping
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/user/_mapping -d '
{
  "user" : {
    "properties" : {
      "name" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "skills" : {
        "type": "nested", 
        "properties" : {
          "skill_id" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "recommendations_count" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'

# Indexing Data
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/user/1 -d '
{
   "name": "John",
   "skills": [
      {
         "skill_id": 100,
         "recommendations_count": 5
      },
      {
         "skill_id": 200,
         "recommendations_count": 3
      }
   ]
}
'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/user/2 -d '
{
   "name": "Mary",
   "skills": [
      {
         "skill_id": 100,
         "recommendations_count": 9
      },
      {
         "skill_id": 200,
         "recommendations_count": 0
      }
   ]
}
'
```

My query filters by skill_id and this works well. I then want to be able to use `script_score` to boost the score of the `user` documents with a higher `recommendations_count` **for the given skill_id.** (<-- this is key).

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/user/_search -d '
{      
    "query":{
      "function_score":{
        "query":{
          "bool":{
            "must":{
              "nested":{
                "path":"skills",
                "query":{
                  "bool":{
                    "must":{
                      "term":{
                        "skill_id":100
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "functions":[
          {
            "script_score": {
               "script": "sqrt(1.2 * doc['skills.recommendations_count'].value)"   
            }
          }            
        ]
      }
    }
  }
} 
'
```

How do I access the `skills` array from within the `script`, find the 'skill_id: 100' item in the array, and then use its `recommendations_count` value? The `script_score` above doesn't currently work (score is always 0 regardless of the data, so I assume `doc['skills.recommendations_count'].value` is not looking in the right place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your specific question, the script needs the nested context, just like you did with the `term` query.

This can be rewritten for ES 1.x:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_search' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "skills",
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "skills.skill_id": 100
            }
          },
          "query": {
            "function_score": {
              "functions": [
                {
                  "script_score": {
                    "script": "sqrt(1.2 * doc['skills.recommendations_count'].value)"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

For ES 2.x (filters became first-class citizens in ES 2.x, so the syntax changed a bit to catch up!):

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_search' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "skills",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "skills.skill_id": 100
            }
          },
          "must": {
            "function_score": {
              "functions": [
                {
                  "script_score": {
                    "script": "sqrt(1.2 * doc['skills.recommendations_count'].value)"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Note: I made the `term` query a `term` filter because it has no logical impact on the score (it's either an exact match or not). I also added the nested field's name to the `term` filter, which is a requirement in Elasticsearch 2.x and later (and good practice earlier).

With that out of the way, you can (*and* should) avoid using a script whenever possible. This is one of those cases. [`function_score` supports the concept of a `field_value_factor` function that lets you do things exactly like you are trying, but entirely without a script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor). You can also optionally supply a "missing" value to control what happens if the field is missing.

This translates to *exactly* the same script, but it will perform better:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_search' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "skills",
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "skills.skill_id": 100
            }
          },
          "query": {
            "function_score": {
              "functions": [
                {
                  "field_value_factor": {
                    "field": "skills.recommendations_count",
                    "factor": 1.2,
                    "modifier": "sqrt",
                    "missing": 0
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

For ES 2.x:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_search' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "skills",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "skills.skill_id": 100
            }
          },
          "must": {
            "function_score": {
              "functions": [
                {
                  "field_value_factor": {
                    "field": "skills.recommendations_count",
                    "factor": 1.2,
                    "modifier": "sqrt",
                    "missing": 0
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Scripts are slow and [they *also* imply the use of fielddata in Elasticsearch 1.x, which is bad](https://www.elastic.co/blog/support-in-the-wild-my-biggest-elasticsearch-problem-at-scale). You did mention doc values, which is a promising start that suggests that using Elasticsearch 2.x, but that may have just been terminology.

If you're just starting with Elasticsearch, then I strongly recommend starting with the latest version.

Comment: Wow, I appreciate the throughout response, thank you. It seems as the filter at the bottom doesn't filter based on skill_id: 100.

Comment: Be sure to use `"skills.skill_id"` rather than just `"skill_id"`.

Comment: I am, and if I remove the inner query{} block with the function inside the filtering does work.

Comment: Can you update your question with the modified request that's not fully working? I tried it with the example data in both ES 1.7.3 and ES 2.0.0.

Comment: You were definitely right that the filter was ignored in the first version of this. I edited the answer to show the proper way to do it. Apparently the `nested` logic accepts `query` _or_ `filter`, but it prefers `query` if it gets both! Fixed to show the proper way.