# Elasticsearch: querying on both nested object properties and parent properties

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have some documents which have nested objects inside nested objects :

```
{
    "started_at": 1455088063966,
    "ended_at": 1455088131966,
    "tags": [{
        "type": "transfer",
        "at": 1455088064462,
        "events": [{
            "type": "transfer_processed",
            "at": 1455088131981

        }]
    }, {
        "at": 1455088138232,
        "item": "tag",
        "type": "info"
    }]
}
```

Here, the main document has several nested objects (the tags), and for each tag there are several nested objects (the events).

I would like to get all the documents where the events of type **transfer_processed** occured 60000 milliseconds after the tags of type **transfer**.
For this, I would need to query on both **tags.at**, **tags.type**, **tags.events.at** and **tags.events.type**. And I can't figure out how: I only manage to query on the tags.events properties, or only on the tags properties, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested objects are actually separate Lucene documents under the hood, so you are essentially trying to "join" multiple documents together to do your comparisons. Unfortunately, this is not supported by Elasticsearch.

[Have a look at this similar question and answer which explain it well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049890/elasticsearch-comparing-a-nested-field-with-another-field-in-the-document).

Comment: Shame. That means I will need to add properties to my nested objects so that I don't need to also query on their parent attributes. Thank you.